# Which is more important Ram or Cpu a typical win 10 vm

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

**Problem Statement**

I am currently running a win 10 vm locally on vmware. This guest os is used for sole development purposes. Mostly running eclipse, vscode and dbeaver along with some Firefox tabs. The vm doesn't perform well. Apparently, its the CPU that is being throttled.

**Setup**

**Current Host**

- **Processor** Intel Core i7-9750H 6 x 2.6 - 4.5 GHz x 2.6 - 4.5 GHz
  **6 core 12 threads**
- **Ram**  16 GB  , PC4-21300, 1333.3 MHz, 19-19-19-43, Dual-Channel, 2x SODIMM . Ram is upgradable
- **Notebookcheck Url** https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-S740-15IRH-Laptop-Review-Best-and-Priciest-IdeaPad-Yet.450378.0.html
- **Screen**    15.60 inch 16:9, 3840 x 2160 pixel 282 PPI
- **GPU**   Nvidia GTX 1650 MaxQ 4GB
- **Storage**   local SSD ,1 TB Samsung
- **OS**    Win 11

**Guest**

- **Processor** CPU 4
- **Ram**   8gb
- **Storage**   80 GB
- **Screen**    1920 x 1080

**The upgraded system I am trying to purchase**

- Processor AMD Ryzen 7 5800H 8 x 3.2 - 4.4 GHz, 57 W PL2 8cores 16 threads
- **Ram**   16 GB, DDR4-3200, on-board, dual-channel
- **Notebookcheck Url** https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-5-Pro-16ACH-review-Ryzen-5000-laptop-with-large-120-Hz-LCD.558244.0.html
- **Screen**    16.00 inch 16:10, 2560 x 1600 pixel 189 PPI
- **GPU**   Nvidia GTX 1650 MaxQ 4GB
- **Storage**   local SSD Micron 2300 512GB MTFDHBA512TDV, 1 TB
- **OS**    Win 11

Here a screenshots.

[image: When I simultaneously launch vscode, dbeaver, datagrip and firefox]
*When I launch dbeaver, datagrip, vscode, firefox simultaneously*

[image: After the apps had been launched and settled down]
*After the apps had been launched and settled down*

[image: After the machine is idle for a few mins with all the apps opened in background]
*After the machine is idle for a few mins with all the apps opened in background*

**Goal**

Make the VM less sluggish

**Questions**

1. Will the CPU upgrade alone will improve VM performance or increasing Ram is must too? As the system I buy will have same Ram(non upgradable) as previous machine but better cpu
2. I have assigned a 4 processors to VM but my machine has one single processor with 6 core. I didnt see any option of assigning cores to vm. Is my assigning of 4 processors to VM ok? or should I reduce it to one processor
3. My native laptop resolution is 4k, when I run VM at 4k or within laptop screen it is sluggish. If I connect it to external 1080p monitor via thunderbolt. Its performance increases. I think the thunderbolt is directly connected to dGPU. It might be using some of dGPU to improve VM performace. I think. Now the new machine I am considering does not have thunderbolt. So the external monitor might not be using the dGPU. I dont know much about this stuff. May be someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to answer.  CPU and RAM are each the most important until you have enough of one, and then the other is most important.  You need to use performance analysis tools like task manager to determine what your bottleneck or short resource is.

Comment: The biggest thing you can do (head and shoulders over memory and CPU) is a fast SSD drive. I have 3 VMs running on such a machine and very smoothly. Hard Drives slow down virtual machines.

Comment: `16 gb` is little bit few for some modern develop tasks but still useable. In other way  [AMD](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Ryzen+7+5800H&id=3907) is twice faster than [Intel](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i7-9750H+%40+2.60GHz&id=3425). But both of CPU's are the mobile segment. Decide by color: if new system's color is cool you should buy it!

Comment: CPU is an infinite resource, while RAM is a finite resource. As in, the way CPU works in a VM is that sets of instructions are scheduled on the host CPU and passed through and while a deep queue can slow things down, there's not actually a hard limit on how deep the queue can go, theoretically. RAM, on the other hand, must share with the host, you cannot issue more RAM than the system has. A basic VM doesn't really need many vCPUs, just 2 is fine unless you have specific needs for more.

Comment: Added more details to the question

Comment: @rzlvmp both have the same color. Tough choice

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised they migrated this question here rather than close it as a duplicate of [this canonical question](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning).

Are you hitting the memory limit? Are you limited by the CPU? Or both? Run your workload and monitor which one is the problem.

Will the memory expansion help? Will the CPU upgrade help? The only way to have proper answer is to run tests yourself on your hardware and with your software stack. Try yourself and you'll know. Nobody else can know what is "bad" performance for you and how it must be to feel "better".

Comment: The CPU seems to be touching the 100% in screenshots.

Comment: Well, screenshots appeared *after* I made the answer. The whole question seems to be completely changed.